# Visual C++ 2017 cannot find include files

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to create a new DLL project with Visual C++ 2017. In my source file I have the line:

```
#include "comdefs2.h"
```

This file is located in c:\tm12\headers. So I added that to the "Include Directories" property in in the "VC++ Directories" section of the project properties.  It now looks like:

```
c:\tm12\headers;$(IncludePath)
```

Despite this, Visual C++ says that it cannot open my header file (which definitely exists).

I should mention that I have several other dll projects on my machine, which were ported over from a previous version of Visual C++. In these projects, the include directory is set to:

```
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);
```

And in those projects, there is no problem finding comdefs2.h, even though there seems to be no reference to my header directory.  I have no idea how this works, and no idea why I can't get my new project to find my include directory.  I can put in a full path to the header and that works, but I would like to understand what the heck is going on here.

Comment: What is the "exact" error message?
Are you building for a platform or config, where this wasn't added?
If you can replicate from a command line build using msbuild, add the /bl switch and verify that the macros are correct by reviewing the resulting msbuld.binlog with the Structured Log Viewer (https://msbuildlog.com)

Comment: The exact message in the VC IDE is "Cannot open include file: 'comdefs2.h': no such file or directory". I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comments. I'm building for Windows. I'm not interested in using the command line at this time.

Comment: You may not be interested, but it's the easiest way to troubleshoot build issues. You open a VS developer command prompt, cd to the directory with your .vcxproj file:

   cd c:\repos\myproblemapp

Then run msbuild using a command line similar to:

   msbuild /bl /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release myproblemapp.vcxproj

This will create an msbuild.binlog you can load in the structured log viewer to see "exactly" what is being passed to the compiler /wrt include search paths.